# Jest Error expected number of calls: >=1 Received number of calls: 0 but mock function is properly binded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am getting a "expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
Expected number of calls: >=1
Received number of calls: 0" error.

My test function is:

```
    test("DD cancel", async()=>{
    getC.mockResolvedValueOnce(autoCompleteResp);
    const {cont}= render(<DDS/>,{initialState: initialStateMock});
    await waitFor(()=>{
    expect(getC).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
   });
```

There is no issue with the getC api or any of the mocks as they have been used else where without any errors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Too little information to decipher but I'm guessing you're using a custom render function. Maybe check whether you're importing from your custom render or you're directly importing from react testing lib. Also, you don't need "const {cont}".